# Putting together an array with different loops

Tags: php, arrays

Title might be a bit vague, but I had no clue how to call this question.

My form has checkboxes in it. When they get checked, their values get posted to my database. However, when they don't get checked, I cannot keep track of the unchecked once, because well, that's how it works, right?

For example, for an event which runs from 21-08-2011 till 25-08-2011, I get the following array back when a guests selects he only needs a ticket for the 21st and the 23rd (ticket is not the only value that will be here in the end result, just for brevity):

```
Array
(
[2011-08-21] => Array
    (
        [ticket] => 1
    )

[2011-08-23] => Array
    (
        [ticket] => 1
    )

)
```

However, I also want to keep track of the other days where he doesn't need a ticket. So, I would need an array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [2011-08-21] => Array
        (
            [ticket] => 1
        )
    [2011-08-23] => Array
        (
            [ticket] => 0
        )
    [2011-08-23] => Array
        (
            [ticket] => 1
        )
    [2011-08-23] => Array
        (
            [ticket] => 0
        )

    [2011-08-23] => Array
        (
            [ticket] => 0
        )
)
```

That way I can keep track of everything in my DB (which is needed for this project).

I'm just not quite sure how I can turn the first array into the second one. I have been trying with for and foreach loops, combining it with my `event_details` array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [eventID] => 1
    [groupID] => 3
    [name] => Moto GP 1
    [startDate] => 2011-08-21
    [endDate] => 2011-08-25
    [number_of_days] => 5
    [startDate_f] => 21/08/11
    [endDate_f] => 25/08/11
)
```

With the data in that array I can calculate all the event days, but I'm just not quite sure how to go about it exactly. Any help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but something like:

```
$selected_days = /* Wherever you get the posted array data from */;

$start = new DateTime($event_details['startDate']);
$end   = new DateTime($event_details['endDate']);

while ($start <= $end) {
    $key = $start->format('Y-m-d');

    if (!array_key_exists($key, $selected_days))
        $selected_days[$key] = array( 'ticket' => 0 );

    $start->modify('+1 day');
}
```